# Starting HTML5 movie over without video.load()

Tags: javascript, html, video

I want to write code to seemlessly restart an HTML5 movie.

This almost works: `video.load(); video.play();`

...except that the video takes a half second to load, which doesn't work for this project. How can I just put the play position at 0 on the existing, currently-loaded video?

This doesn't work: `video.currentTime = 0; video.play()`

...for some reason it doesn't play, it stays frozen.

Comment: You know there's a `loop` attribute, as in `<video autoplay loop>`

Comment: if the loop attribute as pointed out by @adeneo doesn't do exactly what you want, you could monitor the play position, and just before it reaches the end set `video.currentTime = 0;`

Comment: @adeneo Yes, unfortunately the video is stopped mid-play, and then has to be resumed at 0. For some reason, when I set `video.currentTime = 0`, `video.play()` does not work- it just shows the frame at 0.